How to create a higher resolution font at low size
I'm looking to create a user interface that has a high resolution, very clear text while at low font. The goal is to fit more text on the screen because I'm want the user to see as much data as possible. However, right now, the baseline text is coming in blurry.
What can I do to fix this? Is the font asset, font file, canvas, project settings or text asset that is the problem?
For reference, my Canvas is set to the below settings:

My Font is set to the below settings:

This is what the font looks like in Game view in both Free Aspect and 1080 view:

These are the settings of the TMP Text (UI) Component:


What other fonts have you tried?  Some fonts are optimized for small sizes and some aren't.  Arial should work, if you have a copy.

I don't know if it works with TextMeshPro maybe you should use the default one (It's in UI -> Text or in UI -> Legacy -> Text) but here is the solution:

I recommend you to create a new text (because of possible changes made before);
Make sure "enable constrained proportions" is turned off

Set Scale to x=0.3 y=0.3 z=0.3

Set Font Size to 300 and turn on Best Fit

To make it bigger or smaller you should use Rect Tool only.
If you want to make it even smaller you just need to lower the Scale again


Final result appears as:

